# Get all the variables of a SQL Dataset that are the max of a sort order using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have data in a single database table like so:

```
Id        NameId      EndNumber    SortOrder
1         TestA       1            1
1         TestA       3            2
1         TestA       9            3
1         TestB       1            1
1         TestB       2            2
1         TestB       4            3
1         TestB       6            4
1         TestB       7            5
1         TestC       2            1
1         TestC       4            2
1         TestC       6            3
```

I have a LINQ query like this:

```
result = _getService.QueryWithNoTracking<GetNamesId>()
    .Where(q => q.Id == myId && names.Contains(q.NameId)
```

I want to my select to return this:

```
 Id      NameId      EndNumber
 1       TestA       9
 1       TestB       7
 1       TestC       6
```

I essentially want the max sort order value of each id/nameId combination. I understand the select but not sure if/how to use an OrderBy to achieve this.

Comment: *GetNamesId* reads like a method but is found in a context that takes a type?

Comment: result = _getService.QueryWithNoTracking<GetNamesId>()
    .Where(q => q.Id == myId && names.Contains(q.NameId).OrderByDescending(x => x.EndNumber).GroupBy(x => x.NameId).Select(x => x.First()).List();  Order by the End Number Descending, then group b NameId, and finally take first of each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably use groupby for this, rather than OrderBy

```
result = _getService
  .QueryWithNoTracking<GetNamesId>()
  .Where(q => q.Id == myId && names.Contains(q.NameId))
  .GroupBy(gni => gni.NameId)
  .Select(g =>
    new  { 
      Id = g.First().Id,
      NameId = g.Key,
      EndNumber = g.Max(gni => gni.EndNumber)
    }
  );
```

LINQ grouping is slightly different to sql. It takes a single list of items and produces a "list of lists" where every item in the inner list has the same property that was specified for key. By grouping on NameId you get a list of lists, which you then turn back into a single list by throwing away most of the EndNumbers in the inner lists and just keeping the max value

Comment: Well, this query will not work with EF Core because of `g.First()` which is not translatable to the SQL.

Comment: Yes it will not work as .First() throws an exception.

Comment: Group it by ID too then, or pull the Min ID etc

Comment: You can use g.Max instead of g.First for the sql translation

Comment: I can, but it's not me asking the question, it's you. If you know the direction you want to take, why not just crack on with implementing it?

Comment: If you're struggling with getting EF to write an effective query it might work better to raw execute a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id, NameId ORDER BY SortOrder DESC) rn ... WHERE rn = 1` based solution